# Help with TP2825

Tags: pcb-design, analog, schematics, datasheet, driver

I want to create a DVR based on the PB1126 chip using the TP2825 encoder. This encoder performs very well the auto-detection of cameras CVBS, AHD, etc.
On the Internet, I did not find information on this chip. Can anyone share useful information?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the manufacturer of the chip?

Comment: Yes. But unfortunately their feedback line is down or they don't respond. We wrote to them by mail and even asked them to register their project. There is no reaction. There they have only one email and there were no answers from it. We tried to contact our various companies - without result.